# what slows down parsing?

Tags: python, postgresql

I have big XML files to parse (about 200k lines and 10MB). The structure is following:

```
<el1>
    <el2>
        <el3>
            <el3-1>...</el3-1>
            <el3-2>...</el3-2>
        </el3>
        <el4>
            <el4-1>...</el4-1>
            <el4-2>...</el4-2>
        </el4>
        <el5>
            <el5-1>...</el4-1>
            <el5-2>...</el5-2>
        </el5>
    </el2>
</el1>
```

Here is my code:

```
tree = ElementTree.parse(filename)
doc = tree.getroot()

cursor.execute(
    'INSERT INTO first_table() VALUES()',
    ())

cursor.execute('SELECT id FROM first_table ORDER BY id DESC limit 1')
row = cursor.fetchone()
v_id1 = row[0]

for el1 in doc.findall('EL1'):
    cursor.execute(
        'INSERT INTO second_table() VALUES(v_id1)',
        (v_id1))

    cursor.execute(
        'SELECT id FROM second_table ORDER BY id DESC limit 1')
    row = cursor.fetchone()
    v_id2 = row[0]

    for el2 in el1.findall('EL2'):
        cursor.execute(
            'INSERT INTO third_table(v_id2) VALUES()',
            (v_id2))

        cursor.execute(
            'SELECT id FROM third_table ORDER BY id DESC limit 1')
        row = cursor.fetchone()
        v_id3 = row[0]

        for el3 in el2.findall('EL3'):
            cursor.execute(
                'INSERT INTO fourth_table(v_id3) VALUES()',
                (v_id3))

            cursor.execute(
                'SELECT id FROM fourth_table ORDER BY id DESC limit 1')
            row = cursor.fetchone()
            v_id4 = row[0]

            for el4 in el3.findall('EL4'):
                cursor.execute(
                    'INSERT INTO fifth_table(v_id4) VALUES()',
                    (v_id4))

            for el5 in el4.findall('EL5'):
                cursor.execute(
                    'INSERT INTO sixth_table(v_id4) VALUES()',
                    (v_id4))

                cursor.execute(
                    'SELECT id FROM sixth_table ORDER BY id DESC limit 1')
                row = cursor.fetchone()
                v_id5 = row[0]

                ...
conn.commit()
```

Basically I get values from attributes and send them into the database. When I need to process nested elements, I have to SELECT last inserted ID from the database and INSERT it as a foreign key into the next INSERT statement.

The whole process takes about 50s but apparently it's too long for the data I have. The SELECT statements for sure take some time, but I already selecting only 1 attribute on last row.

I don't know if it can be faster since I'm not good at programming so I ask you guys.

Comment: [Don't tag in title](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles). Especially don't make a typo. (be careful next time)

Comment: [Benchmark it](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant).

Comment: You can use a kind of cache instead of selects. The program will be surely faster.

Comment: Does each `INSERT` run in its own transaction? That could be your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have 4 nested for loops. That's why.  It is O(n^4).